# Is there a way to issue an ->exec() without having to wait for the return?

Tags: php, phpseclib

Using the phpseclib library, after establishing a connection, is there a way to issue a command via `->exec()` without waiting for a response?

Comment: which `exec()` method are you talking about?

Comment: While I consider running any system commands from PHP to generally be madness, have you considered trying adding a "&" to the end of your command so it runs in the background?

Comment: You are playing with fire. But if you have already start to do dirty things, you can also take a look on php-pcntl extension. It allows you to fork php process.

Comment: You can use the second parameter of the exec method and pass a callback handler. Example: `$ssh->exec($command, function() { ... });`

Comment: for future lookups that land here, yes, blindly running ssh commands are generally not a good idea. However in my particular circumstance, I'm issuing an async call to a bash script on another server (it's not blind), which has it's own logging and runtime verification (response and output is not dropped).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `$ssh->exec('nohup command &');`.

Also, fwiw, I'm sorry you're getting all the downvotes - you don't deserve them..

Comment: thanks, I figured there was a way to do it via straight shell but wasn't sure if there was a feature of the library itself that would auto-prepend/append required syntax if you just wanted to execute something standalone without waiting for a response.